# MAX on columns generated by SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sum, max

I'm trying to get the MAX on a column which is generated dynamically using the SUM statement. The SUM statement is used together with the 'GROUP by' syntax.

This is the original query, however it needs to be modified to work with grouping, sums and of course MAX.

```
SELECT  SUM(video_plays) AS total_video_plays
    FROM `video_statistics` v_stat
    GROUP BY v_stat.`video_id` ASC
```

As you can see SUM is adding all the values inside **video_plays** as ***total_video_plays***..

But I SIMPLY want to get the MAX of ***total_video_plays***

My attempts are below, however they do not work..

```
SELECT SUM(video_plays) AS MAX(total_video_plays)
    FROM `video_statistics` v_stat
    GROUP BY v_stat.`video_id` ASC
```

How would you get the MAX on a column made dynamically ***without using subqueries*** - Because the above is already placed within one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT SUM(video_plays) AS total_video_plays
FROM `video_statistics` v_stat
GROUP BY v_stat.`video_id` 
ORDER BY total_video_plays DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Hat Tip OMG Ponies for proper MySQL dialect.

Comment: Thanks, since I have the SQL in question nested about 5 times. I think I've gone way past the 'bad practice' line. That's why Im trying to keep subs to a minimal. This does the trick. Thank you yet again! Larry.

Comment: This query fails in scenarios, when there is more than one maximum value in the result

Comment: Why?  The user did not ask for the number of times the maximum video plays exists, only what the maximum number is, which this query will return.

Comment: My excuses. I can't delete my downvote unless the answer is edited :/

Comment: @gkiko you're right, even if OP didn't ask he wants to get only one max value, it's good to be aware. I had this problem, I wanted several rows with max values returned if there was not only one max value and I had to use "WITH" wich is supported by Oracle or PostgreSQL. MySQL can use temporary tables for example. Using WITH in my case: WITH t AS (SELECT nomc, SUM(prix) sum_prix FROM circuit
INNER JOIN reser ON circuit.nc = reser.nc
GROUP BY nomc)
SELECT nomc FROM t WHERE sum_prix = (
SELECT MAX(sum_prix) FROM t);

Answer (score 3):

You can not do what you're asking without a subquery, because you can't run two aggregate functions, one on top of the other.

Comment: Would it have a significant effect on performance? Iv read sub-queries can bog down your resources 

How then, would I do so using a sub query?

Comment: @Beavers: Subqueries on MySQL don't perform well, but that's not the case for all databases.

Comment: Just how bad ARE subqueries in MySQL?  My natural inclination (coming from databases in which they're quite fast) is to use a subquery instead of a JOIN if it better expresses the intent of the query — I gather that's not done in MySQL?

Comment: Earlier today there was a question using subqueries that took 0.4s - I suggested to take out the ORDER BY & LIMIT, which *increased* the time to >60 seconds apparently.  Dunno what version though.  It'll be like cursors - necessary evil sometimes.

Comment: I just hate the idea that sub-queries (a basic design element of SQL) have become "a necessary evil" due, essentially, to MySQL's failure at first to implement them at all and later to implement them properly.

Comment: @Larry: It's a reflection of other peoples experience - I'd think that way too if I never used Oracle/SQL Server/etc.  And every db has its quirks, though MySQL's are more negative than any other I've used (looking at you, `GROUP BY`...)

Answer (score 3):

Will this work for you?

```
SELECT MAX(total_video_plays) from table (
 SELECT SUM(video_plays) AS total_video_plays
    FROM `video_statistics` v_stat
    GROUP BY v_stat.`video_id` ASC )
```

It contains a subquery, but maybe not in the sense you were thinking.

Comment: I don't think that would work as is - I've only done it as FROM (SELECT...`, but that is the only way to do it using the two aggregate functions.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
select video_id, sum(video_plays) as sum_video_plays
from (
    select video_id, video_plays
         , row_number() over (partition by video_id
                              order by video_id desc) as rn
    from video_statistics
) as T
where rn = 1
group by video_id;
```

Comment: thank you.  this is what i needed.  my final query (in case the example helps someone else): ```select account_id, mnth max_month, my_count max_month_my_count from (
  select account_id, left(date, 7) mnth, sum(my_count) my_count
    , row_number() over (partition by account_id order by sum(mt_count) desc) as rn
  from my_summary_table m left join my_other_table s on m.account_handle = s.account_handle
  where date >= '2021-01-01' and date < '2022-01-01'
  group by account_id, mnth) as T
where rn = 1```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just do this?:

```
SELECT video_id, max(video_plays) AS max_video_plays    
FROM `video_statistics` v_stat    
GROUP BY v_stat.`video_id` ASC
```

There's an example here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html

```
SELECT user, MAX(salary) FROM users
GROUP BY user HAVING MAX(salary) > 10;
```

**EDIT**: second attempt, albeit using a subquery:

```
select max(sum_video_plays)
from (
SELECT video_id, sum(video_plays) AS sum_video_plays    
FROM `video_statistics` v_stat    
GROUP BY v_stat.`video_id`
) x
```

Your outer query may well be selecting from a much smaller set, and (depending on your data distribution etc.) may be quite performant.

Comment: The first query will give you the highest single entry, not the highest sum of.

Comment: @Dave: No worries, it's possible MySQL's `GROUP BY` will work, but it's frustrating because the syntax isn't supported by any other DB I'm aware of.